# Date format not coming in proper way in csv

Tags: excel, csv, datetime, format, export-to-csv

I have a date coulmn in database which has data in below format -

"20221208121006"

I am saving this in a csv and it is getting changed to below format -

"2.01306E+14"

I tried to change the format to "yyyymmddhhmmss" using "format cell" in csv but it is changing to hash values like "#######"

Is there any other way to fix it?

Comment: What's probably happening here is that the data itself isn't changing, but the formatting (the way that data is displayed) is. For example, Hash strings are what show when a column isn't wide enough to fit a number so resizing the column will fix that.

Comment: CSV files are pure data, and don't save any formatting information (unlike excel's standard xlsx files which include formatting information in them). Therefore if you correct the display (widen columns, change cell colours etc) in a csv file those changes will be lost when you close the file, unless you save it as a different file type.

Comment: CSV != Excel, there is no "format cell" for CSV data. You are mixing  up spreadsheet terms with CSV ones. A CSV file is a text only format and the data in it is only what is outputted from the originating source. As I remember Excel stores date/times as numbers and that is probably what is being output when you Save As csv.